# Flag difference in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have pandas dataset and want to create a column that would flag the difference

i.e Column B should have the same values for each value in column A and vice versa. If it's not then flag it as 1

| column A | Column B | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Atlanta | GA | 0 |
| Atlanta | GA | 0 |
| Newyork | NY | 1 |
| Newyork | YN | 1 |
| company1 | Com | 1 |
| company | Com | 1 |
| company | Com | 1 |

Comment: `df['A'].eq(df['B'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is updated, here is a way of doing it.
I use this data :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column A": ["Atlanta", "Atlanta", "New York", "New York"], "column B": ["AT", "AT", "YN", "NY"]})
df
    column A    column B
0   Atlanta     AT
1   Atlanta     AT
2   New York    YN
3   New York    NY
```

With pd.groupby :

```
df_gb = df.groupby("column A", as_index=False).nunique()

condition = [df_gb["column B"] == 1]
value = [0]
df_gb["difference"] = np.select(condition, value, default=1)
df_gb = df_gb[["column A", "difference"]]
```

Output[0] :

```
df_gb

    column A    difference
0   Atlanta     0
1   New York    1
```

Then finally :

```
df = df.merge(df_gb, on="column A", how="left")
```

Output[1] :

```
df

    column A    column B    difference
0   Atlanta     AT          0
1   Atlanta     AT          0
2   New York    YN          1
3   New York    NY          1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the order and repetition at each character in column B, you can get the similarity for each word in B to A.

```
def sim_lower(A, B):
        return ''.join([ch for ch in B.lower() if ch in A.lower()])

df['Flag'] = [sim_lower(A,B) == B.lower() for A,B in zip(df['column A'],df['column B'])]
```

Which returns

```
   column A column B  New Column   Flag
0   Atlanta       GA           0  False
1   Atlanta       GA           0  False
2   Newyork       NY           1   True
3   Newyork       YN           1   True
4  company1      Com           1   True
5   company      Com           1   True
6   company      Com           1   True
```